# Finding elements of a vector in dataframe column with different length

Tags: r

I want to check if a element of vector is a element of of a dataframe column. And then adding a column to the df for a flag of found or not (here: 0 or 1)

```
df<- (rbind(1,2,3,4,5,6))
names(df)[names(df)=="V1"] <- "Element_Id"
elements.to.search<-c(2,4)

# Pseudo-Code
for (i in 1:rowofdf)
    if elementof(elements.to.search) in df
        df[i,2]=1
    else
        df[i,2]=0
##########

names(df)[names(df)=="V2"] <- "Flag"
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `cbind(df, Flag = as.numeric(df[,1] %in% c(2,4))` but fyi that's a matrix not a data frame

Comment: A bit late here, but thought that i should response to the comment properly. Richard, you are totally right. This seems to work too. But my programming basics are from c and c++ so my r-code will have some heavy c slang (especially for loops xD ). I'm trying to get used to Rs specific and fast way. But since I'm the only one who is programming in R here, it's far more easy to read the code by my colleagues when it has c-Slang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `data.table`.  (BTW, the example `df` is a `matrix`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(list(df))[, Flag:=(V1 %in% c(2,4))+0L][]
#  V1 Flag
#1:  1    0
#2:  2    1
#3:  3    0
#4:  4    1
#5:  5    0
#6:  6    0
```

Comment: akrung, I'm already using R for around a year now. But I'm still more suited with C-Slang R. This is a very good but heavy pure R-language solution. I solved it with a c-slang solution and this is enough. But due to the fact that i have requested a solution in R, I'll vote for your answer and set it as the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I worked on a solution for this a few hours, before posting here. After writing it, there was a flash of insight.... and it works!

So sharing here my solution:

```
rows<-dim(df)[1]

for(j in 1:rows){  
  elements.to.search<-c(2,4)
  if(((is.element(df[j,1],elements.to.search))))
  {
    df[j,2] <- 0
  }
}
```

But I'm always curious about different ways to get there. So feel free to particapte a different solution.

Comment: Did you happen to look at the comment under your question by any chance?

Comment: Thanks David to mention Richards Comment. I'm still overreading some somments here on stackoverflow due to the layout. But I HAVE read it only minutes after I posted my comment. But since my colleagues are not programming in R, I ll stick to my c-slang solution